# Undefined Reference Compiler Error

Tags: c++

I think I'm getting close, but I'm having this error I've been banging my head against the wall on for hours. I'm missing something stupid, and I've gone character by character but I can't find it.

The compiler is giving me

```
main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `translator::translator(std::istream&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

when I try to compile my program. The command I'm using to compile is:

```
clear && g++ -g -Wall main.cpp -o Pear
```

The three sections of use are as follows:

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

std::ifstream myFile;

myFile.open(argv[1]);

translator example(myFile); 

myFile.close(); 

return 0; 
}
```

translator.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "translator.h"


translator::translator(std::istream& in)
{   
table1(in);
table2(in);
}
```

translator.h

```
#ifndef TRANSLATOR
#define TRANSLATOR

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "translationTable.h"


class translator
{
private:

translationTable<std::string, int> table1;

translationTable<int, std::string> table2;

translator(); 

public:

translator(std::istream& in); 

};



#endif
```

Any ideas? I've tried so much, and I've looked up similar problems, but they all have different sources. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hm. Do you expect the compiler to guess what files it needs to compile?

Comment: @H2CO3 - that's what Java does.

Comment: @PeteBecker That's what it shouldn't do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command line for `g++` needs to include both source files, like this:

```
g++ -g -Wall main.cpp translator.cpp -o Pear
```

Otherwise, the compiler has no idea from where to get the implementation of the `translator::translator(std::istream&)` member function.

**EDIT: ** (from the comment)

> I thought that basically the use of header files was so that it would know where to get each implementation of the file?

This part is grossly oversimplified, but it should help you get the picture. Recall that the process of producing an executable from C++ sources consists of two major steps - compilation and linking. The `g++` program performs them both (it can do just one if you specify `-c` flags, or pass only `.o` files).

The compiler and the linker stages of `g++` do not "talk" to each other directly. The compiler produces the inputs for the linker, and that's where the communication ends.

Header files are for the compiler. Specifically, they are for the first stage of compilation - the *preprocessing*. Once the preprocessor has finished, there is no knowledge of where the definitions came from. Even the compiler does not know it, let alone the linker. That is why you need to "help" the linker by supplying all the relevant sources to `g++`.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. I'm sorry, I'm a bit confused, though. I thought that basically the use of header files was so that it would know where to get each implementation of the file?

Comment: @pgowdy13 - when you compile a source file, headers tell the compiler what functions are available from somewhere else, so that it knows what argument types they take and what types they return. It does **not** tell the compiler where those functions will be found; you have to tell it. There's no rule that source files have to have the same base name as headers, nor that all the functions declared in a header have to be implemented in the same source file.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't linking translator.o with your application.

```
g++ -g -c translator.cpp
```

followed by

```
g++ -g -Wall main.cpp translator.o -o Pear
```

Comment: So I basically need to compile all of them separately? This is the first time I've split up all of my files into separate implementation and header files. I usually just write the whole program in main.

Comment: Yes, unless you use a dependency management tool like 'make' (or an IDE, integrated development environment) you have to specify which modules to compile and link together to create an executable.  Review the site http://edmulroy.portbridge.com/oview.htm or Google "compiling vs. linking" for additional references.  g++ is actually a frontend for both the compiling and linking steps, so you can either compile each file separately (as I've shown) or compile and link in one step (which the other answer shows).  But do accept one of the answers.